# Default ROW_NUMBER to One Product

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, window-functions

I created a table that joins Product information with  Master ID table. Master ID is a foreign key common to product information. So each individual who has purchased multiple products will have a common Master ID. I wanted to get the earliest Product sold to customer - so I used ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NUM, CO_Cd, PROD_CD, Date,
MASTER_ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MASTER_ID ORDER BY Date) ROW_NUM
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MASTER_ID
```

However, I'm facing a scenario where two products were purchased on the same date. So SQL I suppose is randomly assigning ROW_NUM = 1 to whichever product. I want to Default ROW_NUM = 1 to **STATIONERY** and not PRINTER in such instances.
I tried a Case Statement which PARTITION BY MASTER_ID CASE WHEN PROD_CD = 'STATIONERY' THEN 'PA' ORDER BY Date. Need more guidance on this.

| PRODUCT_NUM | CO_Cd | PROD_CD | MASTER_ID | Date | ROW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1854 | MAWC | PRINTER | 10003493039 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| 1567 | PREF | STATIONERY | 10003493039 | 1/1/2021 | 2 |
| 2151 | PSIA | STATIONERY | 10003497290 | 3/2/2021 | 1 |

Output wanted:

| PRODUCT_NUM | CO_Cd | PROD_CD | MASTER_ID | Date | ROW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1854 | MAWC | STATIONERY | 10003493039 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| 1567 | PREF | PRINTER | 10003493039 | 1/1/2021 | 2 |
| 2151 | PSIA | STATIONERY | 10003497290 | 3/2/2021 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had the `CASE` in the `PARTITION BY`, it should have been in the `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT
  PRODUCT_NUM,
  CO_Cd,
  PROD_CD,
  Date,
  MASTER_ID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MASTER_ID
    ORDER BY Date, CASE WHEN PROD_CD = 'STATIONERY' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ROW_NUM
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MASTER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include `prod_cd` in the `order by`.  For this purpose, `'STATIONERY' > 'PRINTER'` and you want it first, so a descending sort is needed:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NUM, CO_Cd, PROD_CD, Date, MASTER_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MASTER_ID ORDER BY Date, PROD_CD DESC) AS ROW_NUM
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MASTER_ID;
```